# Can the functions from reals to complex numbers be treated as functions from complex numbers to complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have recently started to learn complex analysis. This question popped into my head when I was reading the path integrals.  Since we have to consider the derivative of path parametrization in the definition of path integral, and this parameterization has as its domain a closed real interval.

Writing it out, if the path $\gamma(t): [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is given by $\gamma(t) = x(t) + i y(t)$, then why do we define its derivative w.r.t. $t$ as $x'(t) + iy'(t)$?  Is it a consequence of treating it as a function from $\mathbb{C} \text{ to } \mathbb{C}$? I don't think that's true because it means it is precomposed with projection function $p(z) = Re(z)$, which isn't holomorphic. So is it so just by definition?

Comment: It's just like the derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: But why do we have it like this?  Is it just by definition?  I ask this because being holomorphic and being differentiable in the multi-real sense are not the same thing. So this seems like an arbitrary thing to do: to throw in this thing in complex integrals and holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 1):

If $\gamma(t) = x(t)+iy(t),$ then $${\gamma(t+h)-\gamma(t)\over h} = {x(t+h-x(t)\over h}+i{y(t+h)-y(t)\over h}$$ so taking limits gives $$\gamma'(t)=x'(t)+iy'(t)$$

On the path $\gamma,$ we are just looking at a function of a real variable, so holomorphy doesn't enter into it.  Of course, when you start talking about the properties of the integral, you have to have holomorphy to get all the powerful theorems of complex variables.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late comment.  So it is treated as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Nobody pays attention to this class of function as an explicit thing.